# SPView.RenderAsHtml() returns an empty string for views created by hand

Tags: list, list-view

I'm working on a Sharepoint 2010 application and I've got a code calling `RenderAsHtml()` on an `SPView`. It worked quite fine as long as we stuck to the views created in XML, in Schema.xml file of the list template.

However, when the same is done for a view created by the user in the web interface, the method returns an empty string.

The views don't seem to differ in any meaningful way (at first glance, at least).

What may be the reason for this?